# How much time passes between waking up and sleeping?

Tags: watchdog

I use the watchdog timer to make Arduino sleep for 8 seconds and then wake it right after and make it sleep again if it didn't complete the loop for 450 times. I made it so that it will only do its job every 1 hour with a for loop. How much time does the Arduino keep awake until it sleeps again? I think it wouldn't be worth to put power consumption of this to calculation but still need to verify.

Comment: you said 8 seconds every hour ... what are you asking?

Comment: I mean right after 8 seconds of sleeping it wakes up and sleeps again if it didn't complete loop for 450 times.

Comment: That time totally depends on what exactly you're doing when waking up. If you have a `delay(10000);` in there, it will be more awake than sleeping. How does it check that *the loop didn't complete for 450 times*?

Comment: I tend use 1ms to wake up and go back to sleep in my [calculations](https://oregonembedded.com/batterycalc.htm).

Comment: it keeps awake the length of the timeout every hour .... your question still makes no sense ... you are describing a fixed timeout ... within that timeout you count the number of iterations ... you said nothing about what happens it 450 iterations are reached

Comment: @jsotola I am asking the delay of sleeping. It must wake up after 8 seconds because of watchdog's limit. After waking up, it will go right into another sleep for 8 seconds. How many seconds or milliseconds pass between not sleeping state and sleeping state is what I ask about.

Comment: why is this description different from your posted question? ... are you certain that this is your real question? ... please edit your question above .... anyway, add code that lights up an LED at wakeup time and turns off at sleep time ... run the code ... record a video of the LED .... measure the time of 100 LED cycles ... that equals to 800 seconds of sleep plus the "on time"